# sending sms in j2me

Tags: java-me, sms

i wrote a sending sms program through wireless messaging in j2me..but whenever i am sending message they are asking permission for sending mssg.

Answer (score 5):

You need to [sign your midlet](http://blog.javia.org/midlet-signing/) otherwise you will get these security prompts whenever you use an API such as network connection or SMS.

Answer (score 0):

even if you sign your midlet with a 3rd party certificate from Verisign/Thawte you will end up with prompts, the only other suggestion is to use an sms aggregator such as a clickatell to proxy the sms for you

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation is there by design, and from the user's point of view he/she do not want applications to be able to send sms messages without his/her knowledge because they cost money. Your question is in some way like "how can I connect to my neighbour's wifi access point without supplying the required password".